# To which directory should file volume be attached in Kommet Docker

Tags: docker, docker-volume

I am running an installation of the Kommet platform, but I trouble figuring out how to attach a volume related to uploaded file storage.

According to Kommet [documentation](https://kommet.io/home) I am supposed to run it with the following command:

```
docker run -t kommet/kommet -v data-volume:/var/lib/postgresql -d
```

This works fine and I can see that my database data is properly stored in my data volume. However, Kommet also allows for uploading files, and I cannot figure out where they are stored.

Is there an option to attach another volume to a specific location where uploaded files are kept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Running Kommet as Docker container doc](https://kommet.io/docs/q/1ck0000000031/running-kommet-as-docker-container), you must mount a volume at `/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/filestorage` such as:

```
docker run -d --name myapp \
   -v my-file-storage:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/filestorage \
   -t kommet/kommet
```

In your case with database volume, it would be something like:

```
docker run -t kommet/kommet -d \
  -v data-volume:/var/lib/postgresql 
  -v file-volume:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/filestorage
```